# Getting Error when trying to pass an array of object to a function

Tags: c++, arrays, argument-passing, dynamic-arrays, dynamic-allocation

I am trying to pass an array of `Student`

into the function `processStudent(string myFilename, Student* myArray, int &mySize)`.
 But it is giving me different kind of errors.

The Student() does nothing, but I tried to assign them some sort of value, it still give the exact same error message:

In the main I have this:

```
// Create an array of students, with the size of theMax (256)
Student* arrayOfStudent= new Student[theMax];

// An integer that will keep track of actually how many students
// Because when we loop, we want to loop within the cell
// that actually have data or student.
int actualSize = 0;

// Invoke the helper function to set up the array of students
// It passed the arryOfStudent by reference, so the changes
// inside of the function will be reflected when it returns
processStudent(filename, arrayOfStudent, actualSize);
```

The function is like this:

```
void processStudent(string myFilename, Student* myArray, int& mySize)
{
    // Something here, but removed still gives that error
}
```

// In the class Student's cpp file

```
Student::Student() 
{
    // Nothing here
}
```

**Error Message:**

```
new-host-2:csci135p1 george$ g++ -Wall -o csci135p2main csci135p2main.cpp
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "Student::Student()", referenced from:
      _main in cc3fTXti.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I have been stripping and stripping down my code, but this error just won't go away. I want to create this array, and pass it to the processStudent function, so it can set up each one when reading the file.

Comment: sounds like a linking error, how are you building?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should ask yourself some questions that could help you:

**"How do I create new instance of Student?"**
Well, I do it like this: `Student* s = new Student();` - it creates new object and stores the referrence to it as a pointer (`Student*`)

**"So how do I create an array of 10 `Student`s?"**
Well, it's probably going to be an array of pointers to new `Student`s and I will probably have to call `new` more than once... by thinking this way you would easily end up with something like this:

```
Student** students = new Student*[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    students[i] = new Student();
```

... which means, that when you clean it up, you will have to call `delete` on every `Student*` plus you'll have to clean up the array itself: call `delete[]` on `Student**` - and when you realize the ugly memory management connect with array of pointers, it should make you look for simpler and better ways of implementing it, thus you should end up using `std::vector` instead of array, objects instead of pointers if it's possible and if it's not, then use smart pointers rather than naked pointers at least.

Comment: Great explanation of my situation... really nice. Thank you. But of course, with year 1 homework, no vector is allowed.. But I can understand my problem a lot more, and deal with the pointers is quite tricky.

Comment: Yes, I understand your point. It's good to write a program like this in order to understand the basics... but the thing is that you should realize that there are better ways how to code, so don't get used to it too much :) I recommend you [this lecture](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OB-bdWKwXsU), especially the part called "Ghastly Style" at 0:12:50 and the part called "Resources and Errors" at 0:27:30... it will make you think more about it ;)

Answer (score 1):

There error message is telling you the answer:

> Student*’ to ‘Student**’

Change the type of the `myArray` argument in `processStudent()`:

```
void processStudent(string myFilename, Student** myArray, int& mySize)
{
}
```

When an array is passed to a function it decays to a pointer:

```
void some_func(char* b) {...}

char buf[100];
some_func(buf);
```

When you pass the `arrayOfStudent` the array decays to a pointer, it just happens to be that the array is an array of pointers hence the `**`.

---

The linker is complaining that it cannot locate the definition of the default constructor for `Student`. The definition is contained in the `Student.cpp` file so compile all of the source files to resolve the linker error:

> g++ -Wall -o csci135p2main csci135p2main.cpp Student.cpp

Comment: You can still use `myArray[1]`.

Answer (score 1):

The first error (which seems to have been removed from the question since I wrote this) is telling you that the second parameter of `processStudent` is a pointer-to-pointer, `Student**`, and not a pointer, `Student*`. That's odd since you show your declaration with a `Student*` parameter; are you sure that's the actual declaration from your code? Do you have a different declaration somewhere?

The second error is probably because you're not linking with the unit that contains the definition of the constructor. You're calling the compiler with just one source file (`csci135p2main.cpp`), and I'm guessing that you define the constructor in a different source file.

Comment: Yes, the second error is because I did not include my source file for my class O.O . Can not believe how I did not figure it out in the last 2 hours.

Comment: that means you should get some rest ;)

Answer (score 0):

you'd better use a vector of Student (prefer using arrays only with basic types (int, char..) and vectors for everything else).

```
#include <vector>

std::vector<Student*> arrayOfStudent = new vector<Student*>();
/* ... */
processStudent(filename, arrayOfStudent, actualSize);
```

and

```
void processStudent(std::string& filename, vector<Student*>& arrayOfStudent, int& actualSize) {
/* ... */
}
```

I'm not sure whether that would solve your problem, but at least that's a better use...

Comment: `std::vector<Student*>` is a recipe for "leaktrocity". Use `std::vector<Student>` with `Student` implementing _move semantics_, or `vector<shared_ptr<Student>>` or `vector<unique_ptr<Student>>`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is bug-prone hard-to-maintain exception-unsafe C++.
In modern C++, you should use `std::vector<Student>`, with `Student` class implementing *move semantics*, or `vector<shared_ptr<Student>>` or `vector<unique_ptr<Student>>` based on the ownership (shared or not) of your `Student` instances.

And your function prototype should be like this if student array is an input/output parameter:

```
void processStudent(const std::string & filename, std::vector<Student> & students);
```

Instead, if the `processStudent` function creates the array of students (e.g. based on the content of file), just return it as a return value (this is very efficient thanks to move semantics):

```
std::vector<Student> processStudent(const std::string & filename);
```